# Optimization word problem involving perimeter and area of an arched window

Tags: calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, implicit-differentiation, word-problem

I'm working through an optimization problem in my textbook about maximizing the area of a rectangular window with an arched top.

My question is concerns how to think about a certian variable. I'm torn because my textbook offers a point of view I disagree with.  This almost always means I'm wrong of course, but I can't figure out why.

#### problem details:

So picture a box under a semicircle.

Starting with area and perimeter, I get $A=\frac12 \pi r^2 +2rh$, and $p= 2r+2h+\pi r$. Solving for *h* in *p* I get $h=\frac12 \left[ p-(2+ \pi )r \right]$, leading to $A(r) = pr-(2+ \frac12 \pi ) r^2$ *... Speeding through this because none of it is controversial.*

My question is about the fate of *p* when differentiating *A* wrt *r*.  Specifically whether *p* should be considered a constant or not.

The book says constant, so when differentiating *A(r)* it gives a tidy answer wrt *p*.

My feeling is *p* would be more accurately differentiated with respect to *r* when *A'(r)* is calculated.

##### the derivative of *A(r)* as the book has it

$$
\begin{align}
A(r) &= pr-(2+ \frac12 \pi ) r^2 \longrightarrow\\
 A'(r) &= p - 2(2 + \frac12 \pi)r \\
 &= p - (4 + \pi)r \\
\end{align}
$$

##### the derivative of *A(r)* as I have been looking at it

$$
\begin{align}
A(r) &= pr-(2+ \frac12 \pi ) r^2 \longrightarrow \\
\tfrac{d}{dr} A(r) &= \tfrac{d}{dr} pr - \tfrac{d}{dr} (2 + \frac12 \pi)r^2\\
\tfrac{dA}{dr} &= \tfrac{dp}{dr} r + p \cdot 1  - (4+\pi)r \\
\tfrac{dA}{dr} &= \tfrac{dp}{dr} r + p  - (4+\pi)r \\
\end{align}
$$

When I consider the perimeter I think of it as non-constant.  If we were asked to differentiate *p* we would have done so with respect to *r* and *h*.

This all strongly suggests to me that the books answer to *A(r)* is wrong...  but as I say usually the yolk’s on me!